# CSP Errors in Google Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, content-security-policy

[Here are the errors I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjOXn.png)

I wrote a web application that fetches data from LinkedIn badges when a user enters their username and clicks the "fetch data" button. The application displays the badge at the bottom and extracts data from its class elements (such as name, surname, and title). I want to convert this web application into a Google Chrome extension, so I wrote a manifest file. When I load it in developer mode, I get the errors attached. Does anyone know how to solve this?

I asked ChatGPT for help with my extension errors, and it suggested that I move the code to a server. However, after moving the code to a server, the errors persisted since it is a web application. I was unable to resolve these errors.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You must include all scripts with your extension in ManifestV3, you can't load them from CDN.